# Redirect after registration and auto login is not working

Tags: redirect, user-registration, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

the user can register on the frontend form, and will be auto logged in after submission. Then he should be redirected to a custom URL, but the redirect is not working.

```
// Shortcode für das Registrierungsformular
function custom_registration_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); // Pufferung starten

    // Überprüfen, ob das Formular abgesendet wurde
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'custom_user_registration') {
        $username = sanitize_user($_POST['username']);
        $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // Überprüfe die Eindeutigkeit des Benutzernamens und der E-Mail-Adresse
        if (username_exists($username) || email_exists($email)) {
            echo '<p class="error-message">Benutzername oder E-Mail-Adresse existieren bereits.</p>';
        } else {
            // Hashen des Passworts, bevor es in die Datenbank eingefügt wird
            $hashed_password = wp_hash_password($password);

            $userdata = array(
                'user_login' => $username,
                'user_email' => $email,
                'user_pass'  => $hashed_password,
            );

            $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

            if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
                // Erfolgreiche Registrierung
                //echo '<p class="success-message">Registrierung erfolgreich!</p>';
                $_POST = array(); // Formulardaten zurücksetzen
                /*
                echo '<pre>';
                var_dump( $_POST );
                echo '</pre>';
                */

                // Benutzer automatisch einloggen
                $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user($user_id);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
                do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);            

                // Weiterleitung zur Autorenseite des Benutzers
                //wp_redirect(get_author_posts_url($user_id));
                wp_redirect( home_url(). '/redirect/' );
                exit;
            } else {
                // Fehler bei der Registrierung
                echo '<p class="error-message">Fehler bei der Registrierung: ' . $user_id->get_error_message() . '</p>';
            }
        }       
    }

    // HTML-Formular ausgeben
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_user_registration">
        <label for="username">Benutzername:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ? esc_attr($_POST['username']) : ''; ?>">

        <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? esc_attr($_POST['email']) : ''; ?>">

        <label for="password">Passwort:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Registrieren">
    </form>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean(); // Rückgabe des gepufferten HTML-Inhalts
}
add_shortcode('registration_form', 'custom_registration_form_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to work with the help of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23557826/6023434). I think you only need `wp_set_current_user` and `wp_set_auth_cookie` for the login functionality. Here is my revision of your innermost nested conditional, the rest is the same:

```
if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
              
  wp_set_current_user($user_id);
  wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            
  $url = home_url() . '/redirect';
              
  wp_redirect( $url );
  exit;
}
```